# How to get cut a few value in to different col in python dataframe？

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like following：

```
       pop    state  year       value1   value2    value3
    0  1.8    Ohio   2000001      3         3         1
    1  1.9    Ohio   2001001      3         3         1
    2  3.9  Nevada   2002         3         3         1
    3  2.9  Nevada   2001003      3         3         1
    4  2.0  Nevada   2002004      3         3         1
```

I want to cut the df['year'] to three segment in value1, value2,value3. If the value is not long enough, I can fill with 0.
So I want to get  the data frame as following:

```
        pop    state  year       value1   value2    value3
    0  1.8    Ohio   2000001      200       000        1
    1  1.9    Ohio   2001001      200       100        1
    2  3.9  Nevada   2002         200        2         0
    3  2.9  Nevada   2001003      200       100        3
    4  2.0  Nevada   2002004      200       200        4
```

Moreover if the df['value1'],df['value2'],df['value3'] have different values. How can I do in python pandas?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast `year` to take string values followed by [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the specific slices corresponding to the values in the 3 columns.

You could then replace the empty strings with `0` to get back the desired result.

```
In [3]: df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)

In [4]: df.ix[:,3:6] = df['year'].str.extract('(?P<value1>\d{0,3})(?P<value2>\d{0,3})(?P<value3>\d{0,1})')

In [5]: df.replace('', 0, inplace=True)

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   pop   state     year value1 value2 value3
0  1.8    Ohio  2000001    200    000      1
1  1.9    Ohio  2001001    200    100      1
2  3.9  Nevada     2002    200      2      0
3  2.9  Nevada  2001003    200    100      3
4  2.0  Nevada  2002004    200    200      4
```

Comment: Hi Nickil,  I have a question. If I have a dataframe with many col such as value1,value2.....value100. It is hard for me to write the code like this: df.ix[:,3:6] = df['year'].str.extract('(?P<value1>\d{0,3})(?P<value2>\d{0,3})(?P<value3>\d{0,1})').      How can I do it?  Thanks~